# SAC Application Input "Textbox" filter

Tags: sap-analytics-cloud

I am currently getting introduced to SAC and i am looking to filter a table and its columns via a "input field".

I have seen guides on drop down boxes and sliders but not text input by the user.

I imagine the code is very similar?

thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The following code will also include vague strings like "Smi" for Smith, Smithy or Smithers in example.

Make sure you paste this into your InputField on your analytic application.

```
var Input= this.getValue(); 

var i=0; 


var res=Table_1.getDataSource().getMembers("Dimension_Name_"); 


var filter_data = [""];
var a = 0;
for (i=0;i<res.length; i++) 

{
if (res[i].description.startsWith(Input))
{ 
filter_data[a] = res[i].description;    
a++;
} 

} 

Table_1.getDataSource().setDimensionFilter("Dimension_Name_",filter_data);
```

Hope this helps others that may run into this